# What does dot-equals mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

What does ".=" mean in Perl (dot-equals)?  Example code below (in the while clause):

```
if( my $file = shift @ARGV ) {
    $parser->parse( Source => {SystemId => $file} );
} else {
    my $input = "";
    while( <STDIN> ) { $input .= $_; }
    $parser->parse( Source => {String => $input} );
}
exit;
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm surprised that [Perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) really doesn't yield an explanation of this operator. **EDIT**: Wow - turns out it actually does - just in an extremely roundabout way.  If you do a find for '.=', nothing useful comes up.

Answer (score 31):

The period `.` is the [concatenation operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators). The equal sign to the right means that this is an [assignment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators), like in C.

For example:

```
$input .= $_;
```

Does the same as

```
$input = $input . $_;
```

However, there's also some perl magic in this, for example this removes the need to initialize a variable to avoid "uninitialized" warnings. Try the difference:

```
perl -we 'my $x; $x = $x + 1'   # Use of uninitialized value in addition ...
perl -we 'my $x; $x += 1'       # no warning
```

This means that the line in your code:

```
my $input = "";
```

Is quite redundant. Albeit some people might find it comforting.

Answer (score 8):

For pretty much any binary operator `X`, `$a X= $b` is equivalent to `$a = $a X $b`. The dot `.` is a string concatenation operator; thus, `$a .= $b` means "stick `$b` at the end of `$a`".

In your code, you start with an empty `$input`, then repeatedly read a line and append it to `$input` until there's no lines left. You should end up with the entire file as the contents of `$input`, one line at a time.

It should be equivalent to the loopless

```
local $/;
$input = <STDIN>;
```

(define line separator as a non-defined character, then read until the "end of line" that never comes).

EDIT: Changed according to TLP's comment.

Comment: local only if it is scoped.  indeed, `-0777` is special-cased to set `$/` to undef

Comment: @Amadan You made me uncertain there for a while, but no, it sets it to a numerical value 511, which gets treated as a string. Try it and see.

Comment: @TLP: Huh, look at that. :) TIL

Comment: @TLP: Ain't that the truth. How about that Goatse operator, huh?

Comment: @Amadan My personal favourite is the Eskimo Kiss operator.

Answer (score 5):

You have found the *string concatenation* operator.

Let's try it :

```
my $string = "foo";

$string .= "bar";

print $string;
foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

This performs concatenation to the $input var.  Whatever is coming in via STDIN is being assigned to $input.